# Split a dataframe in R into multiple rows per ID based on a date column

Tags: r, survival-analysis

**I have a dataframe in R as seen below:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

# Create the dataset
num_rows <- 1000
fixed_start_date <- as.Date("2021-12-27")
end_date <- as.Date("2022-10-15")
p_na <- 0.6

# Generate random dates for end column
end_dates <- sample(seq(fixed_start_date, end_date, by = "days"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)

# Generate random dates for the test column
test_dates <- ifelse(runif(num_rows) > p_na,
                     sample(seq(fixed_start_date, end_date, by = "days"), num_rows, replace = TRUE),
                     NA)

# Convert test_dates to actual Date objects
test_dates <- as.Date(test_dates, origin = "1970-01-01")

# Create the data frame
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:num_rows,
  start_date = rep(fixed_start_date, num_rows),
  end_date = end_dates,
  test_date = test_dates
)

# Display the first few rows of the dataset
head(data)
```

What I want to do is to split the data into several rows for each ID, if they have a Date in the test_date column.

For example, for ID 1, this should be split into two rows:

**One row with**

ID staying the same (i.e. 1),

start_date == "2021-12-27",

end_date == "2022-02-23" which is the date before the test_date in this case,

test_date should stay the same, i.e. in this case 2022-02-24

Here should further be a new column introduced called exposure, which should be 0

**Another row with**

ID staying the same (i.e. 1),

start_date == "2022-02-24" which now is the test_date value,

end_date staying the same (i.e. "2022-06-23"),

test_date should stay the same, i.e. in this case 2022-02-24

Here should further be a new column introduced called exposure, which should be 1

**For rows where test_date is NA, these IDs should only have one row with all columns staying the same as the initial data but adding a new column called exposure which should be 0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `ID` is unique and there are only two states for exposure, so rather than worrying about grouping, it's easier and quicker to just split the dataset into `is.na(test_date)` and `!is.na(test_date)`, duplicate the rows of the latter group and then combine them back together. Here is a `data.table` approach:

```r
full_dat <- rbindlist(list(
    dat[!is.na(test_date)][
        ,
        `:=`(end_date = test_date - 1, exposure = 0)
    ],
    dat[!is.na(test_date)][
        ,
        `:=`(start_date = test_date, exposure = 1)
    ],
    dat[is.na(test_date)][, exposure := 0]
)) |> setorder(ID, test_date)

head(full_dat, 10)

#        ID start_date   end_date  test_date exposure
#     <int>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>    <num>
#  1:     1 2021-12-27 2022-02-23 2022-02-24        0
#  2:     1 2022-02-24 2022-06-23 2022-02-24        1
#  3:     2 2021-12-27 2022-08-23 2022-08-24        0
#  4:     2 2022-08-24 2022-01-09 2022-08-24        1
#  5:     3 2021-12-27 2022-09-02 2022-09-03        0
#  6:     3 2022-09-03 2022-07-09 2022-09-03        1
#  7:     4 2021-12-27 2022-04-23       <NA>        0
#  8:     5 2021-12-27 2022-09-12 2022-09-13        0
#  9:     5 2022-09-13 2022-08-12 2022-09-13        1
# 10:     6 2021-12-27 2022-01-06 2022-01-07        0
```

Alternatively, if you want to remain in the `tidyverse` here is a `dplyr` approach. I have still called your data `dat`, as [`data()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html) is a function in the `utils` package which is loaded by default:

```r
 bind_rows(
    filter(dat, !is.na(test_date)) |>
        mutate(end_date = test_date - 1, exposure = 0),
    filter(dat, !is.na(test_date)) |>
        mutate(start_date = test_date, exposure = 1),
    filter(dat, is.na(test_date)) |>
        mutate(exposure = 0)
) |>
    arrange(ID, test_date)
```

This gives the same output.

Comment: It looks very promising! Just a few comments:
1. It is the end_date that should be set as test_date - 1 for the first row of the split (i.e. when exposure ==0).
2. For the next row, the start_date should be set as test_date, not the original start_date.

Maybe these things were unclear from my question. If you can edit this in your code I will mark it as the solution!

Comment: Sorry I missed the detail, I was in a bit of a rush to get somewhere - I will update it in an hour or so.

Comment: Many thanks for this Sam! Looking forward to the corect code, very nice solution, works much better than survsplit since it depends on numeric values and one can not use dates directly!

Comment: I have updated it now - hopefully this is what you meant!